# NextCloud Wont Launch

Tags: server, permissions, snap, chmod, nextcloud

I just installed Ubuntu (encrypted) on a surplus server to use as an in-home NAS.  I'm trying to get NextCloud up and running, but it failed to launch and popped up a terminal window with the following list of issues;

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/tmp/locks': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/snap/nextcloud/7658/apache/logs': Operation not permitted
Making sure nextcloud is setup...
chmod: changing permissions of '/tmp/pids': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/tmp/sockets': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/tmp/pids': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/tmp/sockets': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/tmp/pids': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/tmp/sockets': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/snap/nextcloud/common/nextcloud': Operation not permitted
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/snap/nextcloud/common/nextcloud': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access '/var/snap/nextcloud/common/nextcloud/tmp': Permission denied
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/snap/nextcloud/7658/nextcloud/extra-apps': Operation not permitted
Waiting for PHP...
```

I clicked on the set permissions slider, and put it to on, signed off with my password. Didn't resolve the issue.  So, now what?

Comment: I confirm that the snap package halts at `Waiting for PHP...` on 18.04. I looked at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap), [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-nextcloud-on-ubuntu-18-04), tried finding relevant threads in the forum, installing snaps from newer channels (14/candidate, edge/master) no luck. Their [documentation](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/14/admin_manual/installation/source_installation.html) seems to be written with 16.04 or releases prior to 18.04 in mind.

Comment: I would go the route to install from tarball or have a look at OwnCloud instead which have an 18.04 repository.